# Thymeleaf loop error when using its index

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm trying to iterate an string in Thymeleaf, letter by letter:

```
<div th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, #strings.length(name))}">
    <p th:text="${name.charAt(i)}"></p>
</div>
```

This is giving me an error:

> Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating
> SpringEL expression: "name.charAt(i)" (template: "name-list" - line 8,
> col 16)   at
> org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)  at
> org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)  at
> org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
> ... 48 more

If I do

```
<div th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, #strings.length(name))}">
    <p th:text="${name.charAt(2)}"></p>
</div>
```

Thymeleaf does not complain and gives me what I want. Thank you.

Comment: Just a tip: I would edit your question so that it is clear that you are not asking for how to make your code work, necessarily, but rather asking why the error happens above. Please correct me if I am incorrect, but you found a solution, but are trying to figure out why the error happened in the first place, correct?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I am trying to get an answer to my question, I added the last snippet just to prove that a number, say 2, is giving no problem, but if I try with the variable the loop provides, I get the error, in something as simple as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index is going out of bounds. Subtract one from the length of the string for the endpoint of the sequence (which is **inclusive**).

```
<div th:each="i: ${#numbers.sequence(0, #strings.length(name) - 1)}">
```

You can directly use `[i]` to access the character by index rather than `charAt` also.

```
<p th:text="${name[i]}"/>
```

To avoid working with indexes, you can loop over the characters of the string (obtainable by calling `toCharArray()`).

```
<div th:each="c: ${name.toCharArray()}">
    <p th:text="${c}"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. Such a silly mistake of mine.

Answer (score -1):

you can use index attribute as well try with as below

```
<div th:each="i,itr: ${#numbers.sequence(0, #strings.length(name))}">
    <p th:text="${name.charAt(itr.index)}"></p>
</div>
```